# PHP FPM pool www - 100% spikes when executing scripts - how to debug

Tags: php-fpm, apache2, debugging, xdebug

I am experiencing weird 100% spikes of cpu when loading drupal pages. It started several months ago and now Im trying to debug this. I moved same database and files to new hosting - everything runs faster but the cpu spikes are still there.

I installed xdebug, loaded the file in wincachegrind but there is no info about cpu usage of certain calls. Is there any other way to find out what causes cpu spikes? Thank you.